# Is it possible to create database role on Heroku Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, heroku

May be I it is very normal question but I am qurious to know if it is possible to create database role on Heroku Postgresql? i meane using this command:

```
CREATE ROLE "rolename";
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

UPDATE:

Yes. As of August 8, 2017 credential are available for Heroku Postgresql: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql-credentials

> Heroku Postgres credentials are available only to production-class plans (Standard, Premium, Private, and Shield) on Postgres 9.6 and above. Hobby-tier plans include only the default credential, which cannot create other credentials or grant permissions.

---

Old answer:

No. You can not create or modify roles using a Heroku Postgres instance. From [the Heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#connection-permissions):

> Heroku runs the SQL below to create a user and database for you.
>
> You cannot create or modify databases and roles on Heroku Postgres.

The ability to create roles (for read-only access) is something that I've requested as a feature but it's not on the current roadmap as far as I know.

Comment: I found this page hoping for a way to separate an admin role from an application role.  It's a bummer this isn't possible.  Thank you!

Comment: That's a rather glaring issue. Seems they want view only to be replicated DB's.. rather limiting.

Comment: I'm getting permission denied when using the given credentials